# run time error, invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba, excel

The code was below was functioning properly till two days back but suddenly started giving the error

> run time error, invalid procedure call or argument

I am running this code on excel 2016 (windows7).

The statement which has the error is as below:

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=rgExp.Left, Top:=rgExp.Top, _
    Width:=rgExp.Width, Height:=rgExp.Height)
```

Can anyone kindly suggest how to go about?

Comment: What is `rgExp`? Seems like that is relevant.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code ? we can't see how you defined `rgExp` and how it's set-up.

Comment: You sure the `ActiveSheet` is the sheet you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is `rgExp` object in your code, but I prefer to define an `Object` of Type `ChartObject` and set it to my chart, then I can modify all it's properties via VBA.

To set-up a chart object use:

`Set ChtObj = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Top:=100, Width:=100, Height:=100)`

**Recommendation** : stay away from `ActiveSheet` and `ActiveChart` and use referenced objects, (change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name).

After `ChtObj` is set, you can easily modify it `With ChtObj` - see me sample code below.

**Code sample** using `ChartObject`

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddSetupChart()

Dim ChtObj  As ChartObject
Dim x As Long, y As Long

' set initial size and position of the chart object, will modify them later in the code
Set ChtObj = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Top:=100, _
                                    Width:=100, Height:=100)

' setting some values for the parameters >> just for the example
x = 200
y = 400

With ChtObj
    .Left = x  ' <-- you can use .Left = rgExp.Left 
    .Top = y  ' <-- you can use .Top= rgExp.Top

    ' set the source data of the chart object
    .Chart.SetSourceData (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3:D5"))

    .Chart.ChartType = xlBarStacked  ' define the type of the chart
    .Chart.HasTitle = True  ' add title to the chart
    .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart Test"  ' modity the title

    ' other properties you want to modify

End With

End Sub
```